# Beginner Docker-Compose & Django

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm reading through the [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#create-a-django-project) docs and have a question about the first code example under the heading:

> Create a Django project

To create a new django project, it states that you should run the following line of code:

```
docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .
```

---

What I'm not understanding is why we should run this command in the context of `docker-compose run`. It's still creating the folder on our local machine. So why are we going through `docker-compose` to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The point of Docker here is repeatability. Note that it is not the django-admin.py on your local machine that is executed (or the Python version on your local machine for that matter). It is instead the binaries that are in the container that was built in the preceding steps.

By executing the command though the 'web' container anyone with that container runs *exactly* the same version of the binaries and libraries. Thus removing the "it-works-on-my-machine" problem.

Of course in this example (for simplicity) the container is built on your machine just before it gets used; In a real world situation you'd share the resulting container using repositories so that everyone in your team can use it.

Comment: My issue is though, wouldn't it make more sense to build an image with the proper django code, and use that image as it is to create the containers, rather than building an image from a modified container? I believe that has been described as a Docker anti-pattern.